# Check user read access to a particular list item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, permissions, splistitem, spuser

I need to check if a user has read level access to a particular list Item. What would be the best approach

1)

```
listItem.DoesUserHavePermissions(currentUser, SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems);
//here there is also SPBasePermissions.OpenItems..so which one to use
listItem.DoesUserHavePermissions(currentUser, SPBasePermissions.OpenItems);
```

2)
Or is it best to get through `SPRoleAssignment` & `SPRoleDefinition`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EffectiveBasePermissions` to get the effective base permissions of the current user for a particular list

```
(MyList.EffectiveBasePermissions & SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems) != SPBasePermissions.EmptyMask
```

For a particular item (normally under broken inheritance):

```
Listitem.DoesUserHavePermissions(myuser, SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems) &&
                                Listitem.DoesUserHavePermissions(myuser, SPBasePermissions.OpenItems);
```